# The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"` does not exist.

I did:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search "default"
3. Click "Terminal: Select Default Profile"
4. Click "Command Prompt"